# Search for a character string in Html files and output this and the <title>.*</title> tag of the file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to search Html files for a character string across all lines. If the string is found, then this string and the `<title>.*</title>` tag of the file shall be output. The search must be performed recursively.

The `<title>.*</title>` tag contained in the file shall only be output if the file contains the searched character string.

Example input file 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of website 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
the character string to be found
  </body>
</html>
```

Example input file 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of website 2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
the character string that shall NOT be found
  </body>
</html>
```

Example input file 3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of website 3</title>
  </head>
  <body>
the character string to be found
  </body>
</html>
```

Example output:

```
<title>Title of website 1</title>
the character string to be found
<title>Title of website 3</title>
the character string to be found
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39851255/10477326

Comment: You may also find this useful: [grep with logic operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/grep-with-logic-operators). If you want a more specific answer please provide a minimal testable sample of input + desired output.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks. The Input is a html file. The output should be the title tag with the title (search string) and the 2'nd search string if found. Not one of the two should be displayed if the other is missing in the source.

Comment: @Daniel T Thanks for the tip. I have tried this from @Benjamin W.: `find . -type f -exec grep -r -o -H '<title>.*</title>' {} \; -exec grep -r -o -H 'word 2' {} \;` It does not work properly because `<title>.*</title>` tag is output even if the "charcter string" is missing.

Comment: You have an example `index.html`? Copy an example to a [snippet](https://snippet.host/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with HTML documents, I'd suggest using a tool that makes structured document queries, rather than treating the input as simple text. For example, given `somedir` containing your sample documents above:

```
$ ls somedir
file1.html  file2.html  file3.html
```

then following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655588/4440445) you could use `xmllint` with the `--html` parser switch to find all the nodes whose `body` element contains `the character string to be found`, and output the `title` of their `head` element:

```
$ find somedir/ -name '*.html' -exec xmllint --html --xpath '
    //*[body[contains(.,"the character string to be found")]]/head/title
  ' {} \;
<title>Title of website 3</title>
XPath set is empty
<title>Title of website 1</title>
```

Note that for the file whose XPath query fails to match, `xmllint` prints a message to the standard error stream, but also exits with non-zero status. You can discard the former, but use the latter to conditionally print the search string:

```
$ find somedir/ -name '*.html' -exec xmllint --html --xpath '
    //*[body[contains(.,"the character string to be found")]]/head/title
  ' {} 2>/dev/null \; -printf 'the character string to be found\n'
<title>Title of website 3</title>
the character string to be found
<title>Title of website 1</title>
the character string to be found
```

or if you want to print the actual body text *in which* the string was found you can conditionally execute a second query:

```
$ find somedir/ -name '*.html' -exec xmllint --html --xpath '
    //*[body[contains(.,"the character string to be found")]]/head/title
  ' {} 2>/dev/null \; -exec xmllint --html --xpath '
    //*[body[contains(.,"the character string to be found")]]/body/text()
  ' {} \;
<title>Title of website 3</title>

the character string to be found
  
<title>Title of website 1</title>

the character string to be found
```

(note that newlines are not stripped from the body text). If you have a tool that supports XPath 2.0 or greater, such as [xidel](https://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html) then you can combine the matched elements in a single invocation using the `concat()` function (although I haven't yet found a way to make it output one as an HTML tag and the other as plain text):

```
$ find somedir/ -name '*.html' -exec ./xidel --silent --xpath '
    //*[body[contains(.,"the character string to be found")]]/concat(./head/title, codepoints-to-string(10), ./body)
  ' {} \;
Title of website 3
the character string to be found
Title of website 1
the character string to be found
```

Comment: I have tried everything. Everything works as you said. Thank you very much!