# How can I search a file to see if it contains multiple patterns anywhere in the file?

Tags: command-line, grep

I would like to be able to search a list of files for a list of patterns.
The file must contain all of the patterns and the patterns can be anywhere within the file.

Is there some way grep can do this ?

Comment: Do https://askubuntu.com/q/1500670/1004020 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/39851255/10477326 help?

Comment: What will the patterns be? Simple strings? Regular expressions? What flavor of regular expression?

Comment: Is each pattern a single token, e.g. delimited by whitespace or beginning or end of line, or can it be part of larger string?

Comment: [I use silver_searcher (ag)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50403922/4970442), probably [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) would also do the job

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible using grep without running `grep` separately for each pattern (or maybe via some extremely complicated Perl-style regex using lookarounds). But awk maybe up to the task. Assuming the patterns are all present one-per-line in a file named `patterns`, and the input file is named `input`, you can use something like the following awk program:

```sh
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
# test.awk
FNR == NR {
  # First file, contains patterns
  # save all patterns in an array and keep a count
  patterns[$0] = 1;
  count_patterns++;
  next
}
{
  # Not the first file, so check input for patterns
  for (pat in patterns) {
    # Only test patterns if they haven't been seen before
    # Keep count of matched patterns
    if (! (pat in seen) && $0 ~ pat) {
      seen[pat] = 1;
      count_seen++
    }
  }
}
END {
  # End of all input, check if we saw all patterns
  if (count_patterns == count_seen) {
    print "All patterns matched"
  } else {
    exit 1
  }
}
```

To be used like so:

```
awk -f test.awk patterns input
```

Of course, awk's regular expressions can be a bit different from grep's, so you might have to adjust your patterns.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using multiple `grep` commands. Read `man grep xargs`, and do something like

```
grep -l 'pattern1' -f filelist | \
    xargs grep -l 'pattern2` | \
    xargs grep -l 'pattern3'
```

The first `grep` produces a list of files containing the first pattern. The second (`xargs grep`) searches for the second pattern in the files containing the first pattern.

Comment: This will fail if any file names contain newlines. Not a big problem, but it might be worth at least mentioning the limitation.

Comment: I'd expect grep options -Z or --null to remedy that...